# Debug maven application in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a POM (standard web app):

```
<build>
    <finalName>sandbox</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <jboss-home>c:\dev\wildfly8\</jboss-home>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to run this application in Idea 13.1. I created Maven Run/Debug Configuration:

[image]

When I click Debug, all targets are executed and Wildfly is run but debugger window (tab) does not appear and the debug icon is grayed out. I think that the problem is in POM Wildfly configuration. But I do not know what to do. Thanks.

PS I used similar pattern I used in another project with jetty plugin, which worked fine.

Edit: I seek for a procedure that **utilizes maven goals to build** the project.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered looking at your screenshot, you're launching an empty maven configuration, which also runs 2 maven plugins/steps before running itself, something like:

1. sanbox:clean
2. sandbox:instal [this also starts the server]
3. empty maven config

This would result in Idea trying to debug your "empty config" run. Since I don't know if there's a [dedicated plugin that supports managing wildfly from inside Idea](http://blog.arungupta.me/2013/12/intellij-idea-13-javaee7-wildfly-tech-tip-4/), I'd configure the server to allow debug, I'd change my Idea debug setup to a "remote app" and fill in the details. This way the server should start with step 2 and step 3 will start a remote debug session

EDIT: Screenshots for correct JBoss run/debug config

[image]

Comment: Wildfly is new name for jboss which is supported.

Comment: I saw that but since I haven't used it I have no idea if the change is compatible with the JBoss Idea plugin. You can verify it by ensuring that the plugin is enabled, and create a local JBoss run/debug configuration, and just run maven compile and maybe package before actually executing it

Comment: I commented out executions tag and added wildfly:run in Command line option. Currently debugger does not freeze and its window appears. I can see WF starting and deploying my application. Unfortunately breakpoint does not work. To be continued in the morning.

Comment: Like I said, if you keep using that "maven run/debug" config, Idea will try to debug the maven run. You either need to change it to a "JBoss" or "Remote app" configuration. See attached screenshots

Comment: I used maven run configuration with another project and it worked fine. If I go with your proposal then I end up with duplicated build system - one for maven and one with idea because there is no idea artifact to deploy. So I would have to create it and then let Idea build the project itself. But then it will make no sense to launch maven goals to build. If you try it you will find that idea needs different output directory name (sandbox.war) than maven (sandbox).

Comment: Ok, then you could use the other approach I had suggested. Use a "remote app" configuration to connect to the server and have a remote debug session

Comment: That makes sense. I need to alter start up scripts though because I have not found solution how to pass --debug commandline option in maven configuration command line option.